# Execute single Select query for mulltiple values of a single parameter

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Can anyone suggest best way to execute select for a single parameter with multiple value. For example:

Table :          Employee

```
Employee_id      Resigned           City
1                False              JP
2                True               AJ
5                False              AJ
```

Input Parameter woud be something like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 (Employee_id)

```
SELECT e.employee_id, e.resigned FROM Employee e
where e.employee_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
```

The problem here is the return from above query is:
       1                 True
       2                 True
       5                 False

However I am looking for something like this:
       1                 True
       2                 True
       3                 False
       4                 False
       5                 False
       6                 False
       7                 False

When no row presents then return false.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a `left join`:

```
WITH eids as (
      SELECT 1 as employee_id FROM dual union all
      SELECT 2 FROM dual union all
      SELECT 3 FROM dual union all
      SELECT 4 FROM dual union all
      SELECT 5 FROM dual union all
      SELECT 6 FROM dual union all
      SELECT 7 FROM dual
     )
SELECT eids.employee_id, COALESCE(e.resigned, 'False')
FROM eids LEFT JOIN
     Employee e
     ON eids.employee_id = e.employee_id;
```

Comment: I am still getting the same result.

Comment: @LittleMissSunshine . . . This should be returning seven rows.  That is what a `left join` does.

Comment: [As demonstrated by this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/27000/2) @GordonLinoff's query works perfectly (after adding an ORDER BY, that is :-). Share and enjoy.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: Ja, sorry I do have a bit complex query than mentioned above. I am also having 2 WHERE clause conditions on the main table (Employee in above eg). That's why left join is failing in my case.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff : Let me modify my question.

Comment: @LittleMissSunshine . . . It is impolite to change a question after there are answers, if they invalidate the answers.  This tends to draw downvotes.  If you have a different question, then you should ask it as a question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I understand your concern with down votes.. but the thing is that I am in middle of something. I apologize for not evaluating the requirement properly before asking.

Comment: I have revert my changes.. hope this serves your purpose now. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a UDF to convert the comma separated parameters to a Table. This would be a one time script and you can use this function to join.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[myFunc] (@inputStr VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS @TempTab TABLE
   (EmpID int not null)
AS
BEGIN
    ;-- Ensure input ends with comma
    SET @inputStr = REPLACE(@inputStr + ',', ',,', ',')
    DECLARE @SP INT
DECLARE @VALUE VARCHAR(1000)
WHILE PATINDEX('%,%', @inputStr ) <> 0 
BEGIN
   SELECT  @SP = PATINDEX('%,%',@inputStr)
   SELECT  @VALUE = LEFT(@inputStr , @SP - 1)
   SELECT  @inputStr = STUFF(@inputStr, 1, @SP, '')
   INSERT INTO @TempTab(EmpID) VALUES (@VALUE)
END
    RETURN
END
```

And then have a simple query to get your result--

```
Declare @Parameter varchar(25)
set @Parameter = '10,11,12,13,14,15'

    select t.id, ISNULL(E.resigned ,'False')from 
    (select * from myFunc(@Parameter))t 
    left outer join Employee E
    on t.empid = E.Employee_ID
```

Comment: This is T-SQL, not PL/SQL. The OP is using Oracle not SQL Server, so this has no hope of working...

Comment: @Ben Can you let me know how you conclude OP is using Oracle?

Comment: The question was tagged Oracle and PL/SQL by the OP.